# Proving Ratios And Proportions

Tags: ratio

Help me solve this problem!
I have tried it many times but nothing appeared.
This is the question:
If a:b=c:d=e:f, prove that each is equal to (a+c-e):(b+d-f).

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\frac ab=\frac cd=\frac ef=k$$

$\implies Xa+Yc+Ze=k(Xb+Yd+Zd)$

Comment: Thank you but I need more solution but my teacher left me clues and I don't know if it is correct or not: a/b=c/d=e/f=a+c-e/b+d-f       a=bk, c=dk, e=fk and I don't know what to do next, please help.

Comment: @WilsonRoyceOngKing, Here  $$X=Y=1, Z=-1$$